# Parallel activity in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am creating a dockerfile.

```
WORKDIR /abc/xyz
copy xyz .
RUN pip install  a1 a2 a3
```

iam not not aware of all constructs of Docker. Is there any command in  do  copy and pip task run parallel to save time?

Answer (score 0):

Nope it runs each step as a new layer.  `COPY` will perform a copy from the context it is running on so it's different from `RUN` which runs in the the container only.

Docker Buildkit will parallelize as much as possible though, but your `WORKDIR`, `COPY` and `RUN` commands above need to run in sequence for it to make sense.

Comment: I thought copy and pip install are not dependent on each other. If it's the case, it's impossible.

Comment: It should be dependent because your RUN may need something that you COPYed

Answer (score 0):

You can use [buildkit](https://github.com/moby/buildkit) features. Use `DOCKER_BUILDKIT` environment variable.

Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine as a
RUN echo "1 start"
COPY foo .
RUN sleep 10 && echo "1 done"


FROM alpine as b
RUN echo "2 start"
COPY bar .
RUN sleep 10 && echo "2 done"


FROM centos
COPY --from=a foo .
COPY --from=b bar .
CMD ["cat", "foo", "bar"]
```

`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1  docker build -t test .`

Build output:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 339B                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:latest                                                                                   0.0s
 => [stage-2 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/alpine                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 164B                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [b 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/centos                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [a 2/4] RUN echo "1 start"                                                                                                                     0.5s
 => [b 2/4] RUN echo "2 start"                                                                                                                     0.5s
 => [b 3/4] COPY bar .                                                                                                                             0.1s
 => [a 3/4] COPY foo .                                                                                                                             0.1s
 => [b 4/4] RUN sleep 10 && echo "2 done"                                                                                                         10.4s
 => [a 4/4] RUN sleep 10 && echo "1 done"                                                                                                         10.4s
 => CACHED [stage-2 2/3] COPY --from=a foo .                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => CACHED [stage-2 3/3] COPY --from=b bar .                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:1517fa1d98ab568a7b16f91c43b714bdf34406929ddf5c8a992bee5d3d4b942e                                                       0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/test                                                                                                            0.0s
```

It took 12 seconds.